# Tick or untick checkboxes when clicking on the list item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-checkbox

So at the moment I have got a listview, with checkboxes at the end of each row. Right now, when you tick the box the box gets ticked and unticked. But what I want is that when you click on the listview item/row that the checkbox gets ticked or unticked.

here's my code:

```
public class MyActivity3 extends Activity {
private TextView tv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my3);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewcat);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Bold.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(typeface);


    String listArray[] = new String[] { "All", "Friends & Family", "Sports", "Outside",
            "At School", "Fitness", "Photography", "Food", "Beach", "Money" };
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= listArray.length - 1; i++) {
       HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("title", listArray[i]);
        aList.add(hm);
    }
    String[] sfrm = { "title"};
    int[] sto = { R.id.title};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
            R.layout.row_layout, sfrm, sto);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,position, long id) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.your_checkbox);    
    cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
    }
```

This simply makes the item checked if it wasnt, and unchecks it if it was.

Comment: Yes that will be your onItemClick listener for the listview, I just replace yours with this.

Comment: Looks like youre missing the int value before position in the onItemClick method.

Comment: isChecked still remains red?

Comment: Oh sorry thats a mistake on my behalf, it should be isChecked() and not just isChecked.

Comment: This is the code now, why are the ending marks red? http://gyazo.com/0be0fe06bb0dcba1d66bc4ae8eca4816

Comment: Looks to me like you have a } bracket too much or less.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of Zoltish is fine for you but if you create a custom list adapter it will be better for further modificatons of list and bug free coding for each new requirements

if the refered tutorial is too complicated for you try something like this

```
private class checkBoxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {




    private class ViewHolder {

        CheckBox chk;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) atvt
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.msg_receipents, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                                            holder.chk.setChecked(!holder.chk.isChecked());
                }
            });

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        }




        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess so. I'm really new to programming so all is new to me. I don't even know if my ListView is correct. Maybe you could help me set up a correct listview with custom adapter?

Comment: Read this tutoral carefully its best explanation of checkbox in ListView                     http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/list-view-with-check-box-using-custom.html

Comment: Do you have any idea why the ending marks are red? http://gyazo.com/0be0fe06bb0dcba1d66bc4ae8eca4816

Comment: may be you should also do setSelected(true) and setSelected(false) simultaniously with setChecked if the red marks are of selection

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't get it... Could we continue this discussion in chat?